# What could be the possible cause of two identical Python files behaving differently when run?

Tags: python

I'm running an iterative algorithm. I'm comparing two identical implementations of it, in two different files which are copy-pasted versions of each other, but in different subdirectories. Yet I consistently get different results, one file (the same one) always takes fewer steps to converge. You can see the comparison of five runs for each file here:

[image]

The blue one should be the same as the green one (or at least vice versa).

- the code in both files: https://gist.github.com/corazza/a945a6d7929341818e19261f568c4eb5#file-gistfile1-py
- diff of `globals()` output when I embed an IPython shell during runs for both files: https://www.diffchecker.com/i6TcIndO

As you can see in the `globals()` diff, the only difference is in the module name (because they're different files in different subdirectories), and at the end there is also difference in fully qualified names of two functions, but those functions are what the files consist of and they are copy-pasted so identical. Other functions and constants in the namespace are identical.

I'm all out of ideas of what could even be a possible cause of this behavior, does anyone have any candidates?

Comment: have you tried to set the random seeds? I'm not sure if this would solve the issue, but it would definetly increase consistency.

Comment: Best guess is that it has something to do with the `random` package. Try [specifying the seed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) so that it's the same for each module. Maybe `random` is using some characteristic of the file for a default seed.

Comment: Yeah I'll try doing that, but I very much doubt it... It's too consistent

Comment: This does sort of feel like a case where your assumptions might be wrong. Are you sure that green line is always from the same file and you don't have a sorting side-effect somewhere that's always putting green as the faster converging one? Are you sure you copy pasted correctly? Are you sure that the files being IMPORTED are the same in both cases?
You might need to sleep on it and check again with fresh eyes that you're logging and tracking properly.
If your assumptions are correct, the only culprit I can imagine is a namespace clash. which can happen.

Comment: @Neil Most importantly what do you mean by a namespace clash, how could it be a cause? --- Those are all good suggestions yes. I'm completely sure the files are copy-pasted right, I'm also pretty sure there isn't a sorting issue you describe. Regarding importing: I think that the diff settles that? I use the same full names relative to root. I definitely have to sleep on this though it's been driving me insane for hours

Comment: Maybe try a fresh third directory. If it matches one of the first two, then at least you know which of the first two is likelier somehow broken.

Comment: Another idea: rename them so they're switched (rename A to TMP, then B to A, then TMP to B). Then check whether each still gives the same result or whether their results switched as well. Then you know whether it's the directory *name* that somehow causes the difference or some difference in the directory *content* that you overlooked.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode thanks for the ideas, I'll be trying iterations of that tomorrow, too bad this stuff takes so much time to run lol

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue. The main cause was the fact that there was another script which actually launched the two primary (identical) files. The launch script stealthily attempted to load a third file from the primary two files' respective directories. That file contained some overrides for parameters passed into the `learn` function in the primary files, the main culprit being the learning rate for the algorithm. The script failed silently if it couldn't find that specific file, in which case the `learn` function fell back on the default argument. One file's directory contained this file, and the other's didn't, and so the algorithms ended up with different learning rates even though they were identical. Because these were arguments they didn't show up in `globals()`, I wasn't aware of this behavior but should've realized it.

Aside from this, there was an issue with RNG seeding. I set up seeds, but still had completely different runs. This was caused by serializing a set and passing it to a third program for processing and was fixed by converting it into a list and sorting it before serialization.

I'm gonna vote to close the question as too specific.